# Multiple Routes Between two Locations in Mkmapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkdirection

- > How to get one or more possible routes between two points? If anybody
  >   has worked on this can you please tell me?

[image: Want like this]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529970/ios-mapkit-connect-multiple-points-on-map-over-roads/23818032#23818032

Comment: what about RouteObject in this,have you a complete file or project

Comment: Vikas Rajput route will create two points starts and endpoints. location update the last point you can make previous point and can create route

Comment: just see this [link](https://github.com/vikaskumar113/RouteWithMultipleLocation) but i am asking Multiple route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using MapKit

You need to make your `[directionRequest setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES]`then in `response.routes` you will get the available routes

> As is defined in `MKDirectionsRequest` declaration
>
> `open var requestsAlternateRoutes: Bool // if YES and there is more`
> `than one reasonable way to route from source to destination, allow the`
> `route server to return multiple routes. Default is NO.`

## Full code

## Objective-C

```
 - (void)createRouteFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)from to:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destination{
    if(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(from) && CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(destination))
    {
        MKDirectionsRequest * directionRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
        [directionRequest setSource:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:from]]];
        [directionRequest setSource:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destination]]];
        [directionRequest setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
        [directionRequest setRequestsAlternateRoutes:YES];
        
        MKDirections * directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionRequest];
        
        [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(error == nil)
            {
                for (MKRoute * rute in response.routes) {
                    //DO WHAT YOU NEED WITH ROUTE
                }
                
                //here I add the first route
                MKRoute * firstOne = response.routes.firstObject;
                [self.map addOverlay:firstOne.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
                
                MKMapRect rect = [firstOne.polyline boundingMapRect];
                [self.map setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect) animated:YES];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

---

## Swift

```
func createRouteTo(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D,to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        
        if(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(from) && CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(to))
        {
            self.showLoading(message: "Creando Ruta...")
            let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
            directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: from, addressDictionary: nil))
            directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: to, addressDictionary: nil))
            directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
            //THIS MAKE the request for multiple routes if possible
            directionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
            
            // Calculate the direction
            let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
            
            directions.calculate { [unowned self] (directionResponse, error) in
                self.hideLoading(withDelay: 0.1)
                guard let response = directionResponse else {
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title:"Error Creando Ruta",
                                                           message:error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Aceptar", style: .destructive, handler:nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated:true , completion:nil)
                    }
                    
                    return
                }
                
                if(self.currentRouteOverlay != nil)
                {
                    self.mapView.remove(self.currentRouteOverlay!)
                }
                
                
                //in response.routes you will get the routes avaiables
                for route in response.routes
                {
                    //Do what you need with the routes
                    
                } 

                //here I add the first to the MapView
                let route = response.routes[0]
                self.currentRouteOverlay = route.polyline
                self.mapView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
                
                let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
                self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

use this :-

```
 NSString *baseUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?   origin=indore&destination=bhopal&key=%@&alternatives=true”,APIKey];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = 
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
 NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: 
defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(error == nil)
    {
       NSDictionary *result= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
options:0 error:nil];
// this will return all possible roots
NSArray *routes = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
//add The  polyline between locations.    
    }

}];

[dataTask resume];
```